# Compute $ \min_{a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}} \int_{-1}^1 |e^x-a-bx-cx^2|^2dx $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The question is the following:

> Compute 
>   $$ \min_{a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}} \int_{-1}^1 |e^x-a-bx-cx^2|^2dx $$

I tried to expand the integral, and it gives me:
$$
\int_{-1}^1 |e^x-a-bx-cx^2|^2dx=  2a^2+\frac{2}{3}(2ac+b^2)+\frac{2}{e}(a-2b+5c)-2e(a+c)+\frac{2}{5}c^2+\frac{1}{2}(e^2-e^{-2}) 
$$
Here I have no idea how to proceed.

I also consider the following: we can rewrite
$$ \min_{a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}} \int_{-1}^1 |e^x-f(x)|^2dx $$
where
$$
f(x) = a+bx+cx^2
$$
So the question is basically to find a degree 2 polynomial to approximate $e^x$ as close as possible. But  this idea seems to be off the subject I learned. Thanks for any help and hint.

Comment: Hint: $e^x = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.**
You can compute the derivative of $f(a,b,c):=\int_{-1}^{1} | e^x - a - bx - cx^2 |^2 dx$ with respect to $a$, $b$ and $c$ and set them to zero to find the values of $a,b$ and $c$ that minimise that expression.

**Values for comparison**

> We have $\frac{df(a,b,c)}{da} = 4 a + \frac{4c}{3} - 2( e - e^{-1})$ and $\frac{df(a,b,c)}{db} = \frac{4 b}{3} - 4 e^{-1}$. The latter gives us $b = 3 e^{-1}$. Finally, $\frac{df(a,b,c)}{dc} = \frac{4 a}{3} + \frac{4 c}{5} - 2 e + 10e^{-1}$. According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+4+a+%2B+%284+c%29%2F3+-+2+e+%2B+2%2Fe+%3D+0+and++%284+a%29%2F3+%2B+%284+c%29%2F5+-+2+e+%2B+10%2Fe+%3D+0+for+a%2Cc) we have $a = \frac{3 (11 - e^2)}{4 e}$ and $c = \frac{15 (e^2 - 7)}{4 e}$. This [yields](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+a%5E2+%2B+2%2F3+%282+a+c+%2B+b%5E2%29+%2B+%282+%28a+-+2+b+%2B+5+c%29%29%2Fe+-+2+e+%28a+%2B+c%29+%2B+%282+c%5E2%29%2F5+%2B+e%5E2%2F2+-+1%2F%282+e%5E2%29+with+a+%3D+%5Cfrac%7B3+%2811+-+e%5E2%29%7D%7B4+e%7D%2C+b+%3D+3%2Fe%2C+c+%3D++%5Cfrac%7B15+%28e%5E2+-+7%29%7D%7B4+e%7D) $f(a,b,c) =  36 - \frac{259}{2 e^2} - \frac{5 e^2}{2} \approx 0.00144$.

**Edit** Notice that we have $a \approx 0.996$, $b \approx 1.104$ and $c \approx 0.537$, so $a + bx + c x^2 \approx 1 + x + \frac{1}{2} x^2$, which are the first three terms of the Taylor series for $e^x$.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the closest point of $\exp$ to the span of the fuctions $x\mapsto x^k$, $k=0,1,2$ with the norm $\|f\|^2= \int_{-1}^1 |f(x)|^2 dx$
and associated inner product.

The Legendre polynomials $P_n$ are orthogonal, and $P_0,P_1,P_2$ have
the same span as $x\mapsto x^k$, $k=0,1,2$, so the closest point will be
$\sum_{k=0}^2 {1 \over \|P_n\|^2} \langle P_n, \exp \rangle P_n $.